# How do I get span text value in prototype

Tags: prototypejs

This is my prototype code:

```
$$('coupon-value').findAll("price").innerHTML

<span class="coupon-value"><span class="price">66.67</span></span>
```

How do I get the value of `.price` in the prototype? In my html code there are multiple price classes. In `jquery` it would be simple:

```
$(".coupon-value").find(".price").text();
```

But in prototype I have no idea. Can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you would like to get the contents of the `<span>` with the price class that is a child of a `<span>` with the coupon-value class you would do it like this

```
$$('.coupon-value .price').first().innerHTML
```

This will give you the first element that matches that CSS selector. You can also be very specific with your CSS selection as well.

```
$$('span.coupon-value span.price').first().innerHTML
```

you can also select that element and then traverse down the DOM like this

```
$$('.coupon-value').first().down('.price').innerHTML
```

Just be aware `$$()` returns an array of elements that match the CSS selector so you cannot just operate on them like a jQuery collection. However all of the elements in that array are already extended with the PrototypeJS extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$$('coupon-value').getElementsByClassName("price").innerHTML;
```

You can change `innerHTML` for `[0]`

Like this:

```
$$('coupon-value .price')[0];
```

Or even this:

```
$$('span.price')[0];
```

Comment: This is in jquery, I asked in prototype !